# Get comment content by comment ID

Tags: comments, query, id

So I've been trying for a hour or so now to list comment by it's ID.
I've tried the `get_comment($id, $output)` function but it didn't work well, so I went back to whatever is shown below, but it just shows all comments. I want it to show just one comment by it's ID. I can't figure out a way to do it.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$args = array(
    'id' => 1,
);

// The Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

// Comment Loop
if ( $comments ) {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        echo '<p>'.$comment->comment_content.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) makes it seem like you can query for a specific comment by ID, as does the [GenerateWP query generator](http://generatewp.com/wp_comment_query/), but I couldn't get it to work with either of those examples. Even looking through the `WP_Comment_Query:query()` code makes it clear that you should be able to pass the ID in the parameters.

That said, using `get_comment()` is your only way to go for now. Here's what can work based on your original code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Get the contents of a single comment by its ID.
 * 
 * @param  int $comment_id The ID of the comment to retrieve.
 * 
 * @return string The comment as a string, if present; null if no comment exists.
 */
function wpse120039_get_comment_by_id( $comment_id ) {
    $comment = get_comment( intval( $comment_id ) );

    if ( ! empty( $comment ) ) {
        return $comment->comment_content;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

echo '<p>' . wpse120039_get_comment_by_id( '34' ) . '</p>';
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm once placed into the functions.php file. Is there a specific reason to use the wpse120039 in the front of the function or can I delete it.

Comment: Glad it worked! The prefix is just there so it doesn't conflict with any other function that may have the same name. I've been bitten by that before, so now I tend to prefix functions I put here with the question number.

Comment: Morgan, the only thing I'd add to that is a check to see if the $comment is valid before returning (to avoid an error message).

Comment: @ChristopherRoss Good idea. I've updated my code to check for a valid `$comment`, plus typecast the param into an int up front.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an argument to [`WP_Comment_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query#Parameters) that would let you search comments by comment ID, just by the associated post ID. However, [`get_comment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment) will do it. An example from the Codex:

```
$my_id = 7;
$comment_id_7 = get_comment( $my_id ); 
$name = $comment_id_7->comment_author;
```